# Change spans text based on keyup

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change all the text on a page that have tag with an ID that matches the field I'm using.

**JS :**

```
$("#name1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#name2").html(val);
});

$("#regard1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#regard2").html(val);
});

$("#code1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#code2").html(val);
});
```

**HTML :**

```
  <input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="A" />

<input id="regard1" type="text" placeholder="B" />

<input id="code1" type="text" placeholder="C" /><br />

<span id="name2">1</span><br />
<span id="code2">2</span><br />
<span id="regard2">3</span><br />
<span id="name2">4</span><br />
<span id="code2">5</span><br />
<span id="regard2">6</span>
```

But it appears only the first instance is affected. How do I hit all the instances?

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't have more than one element with the same ID, that's why jQuery only targets the first element with any given ID, it doesn't expect there to be more elements with the same ID, as that's invalid. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because id should be unique in same document, you should replace the duplicated `ids` by `classes` and the code will work, check working example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("#name1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(".name2").html(val);
});

$("#regard1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(".regard2").html(val);
});

$("#code1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(".code2").html(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name1" type="text" placeholder="A" />

<input id="regard1" type="text" placeholder="B" />

<input id="code1" type="text" placeholder="C" /><br />

<span class="name2">1</span><br />
<span class="code2">2</span><br />
<span class="regard2">3</span><br />
<span class="name2">4</span><br />
<span class="code2">5</span><br />
<span class="regard2">6</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html an id can occur be used once. So, you cannot have two elements with the same id. Either give the two elements each a unique id or give them the same class name.